# Viewport Shading Question

Tags: shaders

How can I made shape/edges of the car to be seen better?

I got those results in Shade Mode:

[image]

[image]

I want some more contrast with shapes/edges/shadows seen.
Even sketch looking view like this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: As Chris says, there are a lot of option in the Viewport Shading panel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cube with one face deleted using the default settings:

[image]

As commented above you can play with the <kbd>Viewport Shading</kbd> settings (1). Turn on <kbd>Cavity</kbd> (2) and try using different <kbd>Studio Lighting</kbd> settings (3) and then (4). The image below shows the same cube with all those settings applied:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I have done exactly what you advice me. Thanks for print screen!

Answer (score 2):

maybe turn on cavity, so see edges better:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you can do additionally to what is given in the other answers is enabling *Wireframe*  in the *Viewport Overlays*, although this might be too much visible edges for your liking. The slider for *Wireframe* can reduce the visible edges, but I don't think this works well. If you don't want the edges so prominently black, you can reduce the *Opacity* next to the *Wireframe*.

[image: wireframe enabled]

[image: wireframe reduced]

[image: opacity reduced]